# Using win.on event in renderer process gives error on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Electron app version 8.0.2

**Issue Details**
Using events in renderer process

```
let win = require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow();
win.on('focus', ()=>{
  console.log('focused');
});
win.on('blur', ()=>{
  console.log('blured');
});
```

Throws error on development console
saying

```
Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released.
```

**Expected Behavior**
It should run without error or warnings

**Actual Behavior**
throw continuous warnings on console

**To Reproduce**
https://gist.github.com/AtiqGauri/1cea1c548025faa77f9f29008ca5a5fe#file-main-js-L4

**Screenshots**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron telling you that you haven't cleaned up correctly and a listener exists on a remote object from a renderer that does not exist any more.

**Solution - Avoid using remote or clean up your event handlers on remote objects if you have to use it**

Add event remover in your code where you had added events code

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
    win.removeAllListeners();
};
```

This will remove **ALL** listeners attached to your window before unloading it.

**Note -**  `onbeforeunload` will be called before page is refreshed or closed.